# Hide item in Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to hide an item in Action Bar Sherlock. I try it:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {    
        case 2131165381:
           item.setVisible(false);
           supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
           CopyOfAsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
           item.setVisible(true);
        break;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use rather resource `id` of `<item>` instead of your "ambicious" number.

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {    
   case R.id.myItem:
     menu.findItem(R.id.myItem).setVisible(false);
   break;
   ...
}
```

From first look at your code i don't know exactly what number 2131165381 is? If you'll work in team it'll be not very human-readable especially for another person.

**Note:** To get more control over menu i recommend you to create second menu variable e.q:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    ...
}
```